# Is there a way to get better debug messages with Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am using 2.4.. Interested in seeing

1) what HTTP URL / parameters are called to FB servers
2) What the responses are returned from FB servers

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my own answer.

In FacebookAds/Logger/NullLogger.php, change these two functions:

public function logRequest(
    $level, RequestInterface $request, array $context = array()) {

```
echo "[REQUEST]<BR /><pre>".print_r($request->getUrl(), true)."</pre><br /><pre>".print_r($request->getBodyParams(), true)."</pre><br />[/REQUEST]<br /><br />";
```

}

public function logResponse(
    $level, ResponseInterface $response, array $context = array()) {

```
echo "[RESPONSE]<br /><pre>".print_r($response->getContent(), true)."</pre><br /><pre>[/RESPONSE]</pre><br /><br />";
```

}